# Can I upgrade my MSR Wisperlite International to also be able to burn propane?

Tags: gear, liquid-fuel-stoves, canister-stoves

I used someone else's Wisperlite Universal for the duration of a trip and it looks like the only functional difference is a jet that can be attached for burning propane. Can I purchase just that jet and burn propane with my Wisperlite International?

Comment: I believe the universal also has a modified fuel line, but I don't have any references for you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question honestly could be too localized on these specific products. However, considering the ubiquity of these stoves I find it is probably quite useful information to know if they could have interchangeable parts.

MSR's Whisperlite International & Universal stoves are very similar products, but they have some fairly notable differences. Let's call the [Whisperlite International](http://www.cascadedesigns.com/msr/stoves/simple-cooking/whisperlite-international-2012/product) the WLI and the [Whisperlite Universal](http://www.cascadedesigns.com/msr/stoves/simple-cooking/whisperlite-universal/product) the WLU just to make it a bit easier.

**Let's look at the WLI & WLU parts first:**

[image: Whisperlite International]

*taken from [MSR WLI product manual](http://media.cascadedesigns.com/pdf/MSR_WLI_StoveInst_EN_USJC_LORES.pdf)*

[image: Whisperlite Universal]

*taken from [MSR WLU product manual](http://media.cascadedesigns.com/pdf/MSR_WLU_StovInst_EN_USJC_LOWRES.pdf)*

As you know, the WLU is the newest iteration of this famous stove that is compatible with not only multiple liquid fuels, but also canister fuels. To achieve this the WLU departs in design from the WLI by having two adapters on the fuel line: one to connect to a canister and one to connect to the traditional MSR pump. This means the WLU's fuel line and generator tube are different parts from the WLI. The WLU has a UC jet that is designed for use with canisters in addition to the liquid fuel UK and UG jets used for both stoves. *(The older model WLI uses different jets than the current model WLI.)* The WLU also includes a canister stand for more efficient burning in cold weather and with low fuel.

**So theoretically a WLI could be converted to a WLU with the following parts:**

- Fuel line and generator tube
- Liquid fuel line adapter
- Canister fuel line adapter
- UC jet for use with canisters
- Canister stand

However, purchasing these parts would take a call to customer service of Cascade Designs, as they are not available through standard channels. Though your local MSR outdoor retailer may be able to order these parts for you. The real issue is going to be whether the cost of these parts is actually much cheaper than buying the WLU.

Either way, it does seem possible to convert at least the current generation WLI into a WLU.

Comment: This is a phenomenal answer! I noticed, however, that the two links in your second paragraph are dead. They still go to Cascade Designs, so hopefully the products are still there. I would have tried to replace them for you, but I don't understand any of these types of stove, so I didn't dare!

Answer (score 2):

Hi I bought a standard gas canister adapter from ebay, some 6mm fuel line and two high quality butterfly clamps to connect the fuel line to the stove and the gas canister adapter.  It works really well and a very cheap solution the only caution is that you need good quality clamps and good quality fuel line.   This is not supported by MSR and is done at your own risk, that said 2 yrs in still happy with my MOD.

Comment: I don't see the connection to the jet this question asks about?

Answer (score 0):

This is my Solution to a Gas conversion,
I bought.

1. MSR WhisperLite Universal C Jet (07381) [image] £4 + p&p
2. Short piece of gas hose £1.71
3. Canister adapter/Valve   £5.88
4. 2 x Hose clamps (butterfly)  £2.06

Then a picture paints a thousand words

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xfRd.jpg)
[image]